# Search by @ keyword with multi_match using Elastic Search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am trying to search email address with @ keyword buy not working. Can you please help me for?

```
$params = [
    'index' => DATABASE,
    'type' => 'XYZ',
    'body' =>[
        'from' => 0,
        'size' => 20,
        'query'=>[
            'multi_match' => [
            'query' => '@gmail.com',
            'fields' => [
                'email',
                '_all'          
            ],                  
            "operator" => 'AND'
        ]
    ],
    'sort' => ['_score']
]
];
```

Comment: it works searchin only google.com ? Could you post your index mapping?

Comment: Even ".com" also not working

Comment: As I imagined, Maybe this happens thanks to the keyword datatype of email field. Could you post your index mapping? GET <your_index_name>/_mappings

Comment: Can you provide your response